# How can I get the referer for a socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a simple node.js web server and I use socket.io.

The users can perform simple tasks on the server, which is a single page application running on `/`. If a user has an existing state on the server, the user's ID could be appended to the URL, e.g. `/{my-id}`.

I need to extract the ID from the URL when a socket.io connection is established. Is it any way to get the URL for the client page where the socket is created from; the referrer of the connection request?

Comment: What version of Socket.IO are you using, and how are you setting up the web server?

Comment: I'm using socket.io version 1.0.6. The web server is using the native http module, and socket.io is attached to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `console.log` I managed to find this value like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var referer = socket.request.headers.referer;
});
```

It works, but as it is not documented, I don't know if this is recommended, or if it's going to change.

Comment: This only shows the original URL of the hosting domain connecting to sockets with a static index.html page.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. This generates only the URL

Answer (score 1):

The referrer (referer) header is not sent with a WebSocket open request, only the **origin**

The behavior you're witnessing is probably due to a Socket.IO placeholder for a future time where this data might be passed, as it would be useful in some instances. The referer property seemingly just points to the origin header.

According to WHATWG maintainers, there simply hasn't been any interest adding the referrer:

"IIRC, up to now, we haven't received any request from developers to send a referrer."

https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/630