# How to get referrer URL from remote domain when using socket.io and a static index.html

Tags: node.js, http, express, socket.io

Let's say my site with a socket.io connection created in `index.html` is `https://example_A.com/mysockets/index.html`, and a remote website `https://example_B.com/somerandomwebpage` has a link to my site.

How can I get the remote referrer's URL?

I found this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044769/how-can-i-get-the-referer-for-a-socket-io-connection), which states to use the following:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var referer = socket.request.headers.referer;
}
```

However, this only returns the URL of my own server which is serving up `index.html` using express. Since `https://example_A.com/mysockets/index.html` is making the connection to sockets using `io.on()`, it makes sense that the referrer would be my own site.

How can I get the remote referrer's URL instead of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question in my question without realizing.. Since express is serving up index.html, I need to get the referrer in express with:

```
req.header('Referer');
```